# show data in gridview only some words

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm use grid view for show recent messages...there use datasource...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" Width="586px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="show" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" 
                                                SortExpression="user_id" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="user_name" 
                                                SortExpression="user_name" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="sender_mail" HeaderText="sender_mail" 
                                                SortExpression="sender_mail" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="message" HeaderText="message" ReadOnly="True" 
                                                SortExpression="message" ControlStyle-Width="70px" ControlStyle-Height="25">
                                            <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="50px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Height="10px" Width="70px" />
                                            <ItemStyle Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="70px" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

there in my database if message is too long then it show in one field...
ex:-msg is 'hi how are you'
it show full msg......but i show data only 'hi how...'
i'm also try set width and height but not work.

Comment: you should do it in your select command procedure. there are lots of way to get required sunstring from a table. you can use "Left", "Substring" etc.. in sql server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template field instead of the boundfield.

```
    <asp:TemplateField >
    <HeaderTemplate>Message</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("message").ToString().Substring(0,10) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemtemplate>
              <asp:textbox id="Textbox1"
                text='<%#Eval("message")%>'
                width="90"
                runat="server"/>                                      
            </Edititemtemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here we are taking a substring of the message (10 characters only). you can modify to suit your needs.

Comment: tenx for that answer it work perfect but there when i'm click select button there not show full msg in text box....there is code                     

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                Int16 num = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
                Label8.Text = GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Text;
                Label9.Text = GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Text;
                msgtextbox.Text = GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[4].Text;
            }

Comment: @user2154272 I've modified it to include an edit item template as well .. this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding method to your code that take the msg from DB or just string then you make on that string whatever you want(cut the string at specific index then add ...). And that method then return the processed string back

```
public string cutString(string msg)
   {
      int msgLength = 100;
      return msg.Substring(0, msgLength) + "...";
   }

<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# cutString(Eval("message").ToString())%>' />
```